# How use jmockit without junit

Tags: jmockit

How use jmockit without junit? not use annotation
run main:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JMockit jMockit = new JMockit(JmockitTest.class);

        // to do
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MockUp API outside of tests, but not the Expectations API; the latter can only be used from JUnit or TestNG  tests.